# MySql: merge three tables together

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to merge three tables together as shown here:

[image: merge three tables T1, T2 and T3 together]

Basically I want to include the items from all three tables T1, T2 and T3 and have them merged as shown in the result table. I tried something like this:

```
SELECT T1.user, T2.tid, T2.name, T3.type, T1.mid
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.mid = T2.mid
LEFT JOIN T3 ON T2.tid = T3.tid
GROUP BY T1.user;
```

But it does not seem to have worked. It does show the results but only unique values. In the result if `user` is `johny`, it will only show the first value and ignore the second, though it should be in the result table.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Changed your tag to `join` since `merge-table` is unclear.

Comment: @Michael you were right. Thanks, it's fine. Do you know how can i sort the users. I guess i have to use ORDER BY here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Group is not necessary if you want to see all results for each of the users. Otherwise it will hide some of the rows and show just one per user.

First join T1 Right to T2 than Left Join to T3. This is good practice if there is element from T1 that has no connection with element from T3 to prevent showing NULL result for T£ fields.

```
SELECT T1.user, T2.tid, T2.name, T3.type, T1.mid
FROM T1
RIGHT JOIN T2 ON T1.mid = T2.mid
LEFT JOIN T3 ON T2.tid = T3.tid;
```

Comment: Yes RIGHT JOIN is better. Since i had this problem and i was using WHERE with T2.tid != 'NULL' in addition to the above query. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Get rid of the "Group By" part.  This should fix your problem.

Comment: thank you so much, this was the problem. Its working fine now

Answer (score 4):

Eliminate the `GROUP BY`. There's no need for it in this query.

```
SELECT T1.user, T2.tid, T2.name, T3.type, T1.mid
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.mid = T2.mid
LEFT JOIN T3 ON T2.tid = T3.tid;
```

Comment: thank you, yes that was exactly the problem, its working now.